# What does mysql-connector-java jar mean?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am connecting to MySQL Server which is on my Local Host and in my Local Host It's on Port Number 3306 and In that MySQL Server I am going and connecting to the database and to access that the Credentials are...
The Username is root.
The password is root.

Could anyone explain to me what does  MySQL-connector-java jar mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jar file is a collection of Java classes (usually a library). And `mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar` is version 8.0.12 of the [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) JDBC driver. A JDBC driver is used to connect to a database, in this case to MySQL.

For information on how to connect to MySQL, see [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Could you please let me know are both MySQL-Connector-Java.jar and JDBC driver same?

Comment: @ManideepLatchupatula Not exactly, MySQL Connector/J is **a** JDBC driver (for MySQL), but there are a lot of other JDBC drivers (for other database systems).